# BeautifulSoup data scraping and database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a website.

Now my problem is the following: I want to write all this into a DB (like sqlite) with the number of minute in which a goal was made (this information I can get from the link I get) but this is possible only in the case that the goal count is not `? - ?`, as there isn't any goal made.

```
from pprint import pprint
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livescore.com/soccer/champions-league/'))

data = []
for match in soup.select('table.league-table tr'):
    try:
        team1, team2 = match.find_all('td', class_=['fh', 'fa'])
    except ValueError:  # helps to skip irrelevant rows
        continue

    score = match.find('a', class_='scorelink').text.strip()
    data.append({
        'team1': team1.text.strip(),
        'team2': team2.text.strip(),
        'score': score
    })

pprint(data)

href_tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class':"scorelink"})

links = []

for x in xrange(1, len(href_tags)):
    insert = href_tags[x].get("href");links.append(insert)

print links
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the parser returns in the case of goals/not goals? Otherwise I'm not really sure how to be help

Comment: Hi! Yes. The thing would be like this: I have on one side all the links to the games. On the other side, I've got the matches and who won or not. With that in mind, I want to compare the two and when the score is not ? - ? I should download that link, and inside parse the minute in which the goal was made, then insert into a DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what sense does a score make if it is not coming with the teams played in the game?

The idea is to iterate over every row in every table having `league-table` class. For every row, get the team names and score. Collect the results into a list of dictionaries:

```
from pprint import pprint
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livescore.com/soccer/champions-league/'))

data = []
for match in soup.select('table.league-table tr'):
    try:
        team1, team2 = match.find_all('td', class_=['fh', 'fa'])
    except ValueError:  # helps to skip irrelevant rows
        continue

    score = match.find('a', class_='scorelink').text.strip()
    data.append({
        'team1': team1.text.strip(),
        'team2': team2.text.strip(),
        'score': score
    })

pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {'score': u'? - ?', 'team1': u'Atletico Madrid', 'team2': u'Malmo FF'},
    {'score': u'? - ?', 'team1': u'Olympiakos', 'team2': u'Juventus'},
    {'score': u'? - ?', 'team1': u'Liverpool', 'team2': u'Real Madrid'},
    {'score': u'? - ?', 'team1': u'PFC Ludogorets Razgrad', 'team2': u'Basel'},
    ...
]
```

Note that currently it appends every match, even if it wasn't yet played. If you need to collect the matches that have a score, you can simply check if the `score` is not equal to `? - ?`:

```
if score != '? - ?':
    data.append({
        'team1': team1.text.strip(),
        'team2': team2.text.strip(),
        'score': score
    })
```

The output in this case would be:

```
[{'score': u'2 - 2', 'team1': u'CSKA Moscow', 'team2': u'Manchester City'},
 {'score': u'3 - 0', 'team1': u'Zenit St. Petersburg', 'team2': u'Standard Liege'},
 {'score': u'4 - 0', 'team1': u'APOEL Nicosia', 'team2': u'AaB'},
 {'score': u'3 - 0', 'team1': u'BATE Borisov', 'team2': u'Slovan Bratislava'},
 {'score': u'0 - 1', 'team1': u'Celtic', 'team2': u'Maribor'},
 {'score': u'2 - 0', 'team1': u'FC Porto', 'team2': u'Lille'},
 {'score': u'1 - 0', 'team1': u'Arsenal', 'team2': u'Besiktas'},
 {'score': u'3 - 1', 'team1': u'Athletic Bilbao', 'team2': u'SSC Napoli'},
 {'score': u'4 - 0', 'team1': u'Bayer Leverkusen', 'team2': u'FC Koebenhavn'},
 {'score': u'3 - 0', 'team1': u'Malmo FF', 'team2': u'Salzburg'},
 {'score': u'1 - 0', 'team1': u'PFC Ludogorets Razgrad *', 'team2': u'Steaua Bucuresti'}]
```

---

As for "writing into the database" part, you can use [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module and `executemany()` with [`named parameters`](http://pymotw.com/2/sqlite3/#named-parameters):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
conn.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches (
        id    integer primary key autoincrement not null,
        team1  text,
        team2 text,
        score text
    )""")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        matches (team1, team2, score) 
    VALUES 
        (:team1, :team2, :score)""", data)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

There are certainly other things to improve or talk about, but I think this is a good start for you.